# Linking Multiple Radio Buttons Together To Open Different URLs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I am pretty new to HTML/Javascript but am trying to link some radio buttons together for a form so that depending on the outcome they link to different URLs. For example:

Radio 1) select from: A and B

if A was selected link to Radio 2

if B was selected link to Radio 3

Radio 2) select from: C D E

OR

Radio 3) select from: F G H I

*SUBMIT BUTTON* opens one of the following URLs in the same window:

if C link to URL1

if D link to URL2

if E link to URL3

if F link to URL4

if G link to URL 5

if H link to URL 6

if I link to URL 7

Any suggestions on the best way to go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you !!

```
<div id="Radio1">
    <label for="html">A</label>
    <input type="radio" value="A" name="radio" onclick="radio2()" id="0">
    <label for="html">B</label>
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="radio" onclick="radio3()" id="1">
</div>
<div id="Radio2">
    <label for="html">C</label>
    <input type="radio" value="C" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="2">
    <label for="html">D</label>
    <input type="radio" value="D" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="3">
    <label for="html">E</label>
    <input type="radio" value="E" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="4">
</div>
<div id="Radio3">
    <label for="html">F</label>
    <input type="radio" value="F" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="5">
    <label for="html">G</label>
    <input type="radio" value="G" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="6">
    <label for="html">H</label>
    <input type="radio" value="H" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="7">
    <label for="html">I</label>
    <input type="radio" value="I" name="radio" onclick="url()" id="8">
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

script

```
<script>
    let allUrl=["https://www.w3schools.com/html/","https://www.w3schools.com/css/","https://www.w3schools.com/js/","https://reactjs.org/","https://www.python.org/","https://angular.io/"]
    let radio2=()=>{
        document.getElementById("Radio2").style.display="contents"
        document.getElementById("Radio3").style.display="none"
    }
    let radio3=()=>{
        document.getElementById("Radio3").style.display="contents"
        document.getElementById("Radio2").style.display="none"
    }
    let url=()=>{
        window.open(allUrl[event.target.id])
    }
</script>
```

css

```
#Radio2{
    display:none;
}
#Radio3{
    display:none;
}
```